# How to turn off GNOME hint bubbles?

Tags: fedora, gnome

How can I disable the bubbles that pop up after ~1 sec? I don't want hint bubbles! :)

[Gnome pop-up help bubble http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/4403/screenshotrj.png](http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/4403/screenshotrj.png)

Answer (score 2):

1. Open or create the file `~/.gtkrc-2.0`
2. Add this line: `gtk-enable-tooltips = 0`
3. Logout and log back in (or switch to another gnome theme then switch back to your theme).